# 403 Forbidden Access error with AntiForgeryToken - is it client side or server side issue?

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-403, antiforgerytoken

I'm having an issue when users try to submit a form on a website. It will occasionally throw a 403 Forbidden Access error and using googles development tools I noticed the error is thrown due to an issue with the AntiForgeryToken. I cannot determine if this is being caused by the client or server firewall as trying to enable logging on the error does not work and seems to throw a generic chrome 403 page rather than the page I have designed for this error.

Here is the network tracking log for the error:

Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
403 Forbidden
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection:
Keep-Alive
Content-Length:
199
Content-Type:
text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:
Thu, 31 Oct 2023 12:49:39 GMT
Keep-Alive:
timeout=15, max=100
Server:
Apache
Accept:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
en-GB,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Cache-Control:
max-age=0
Connection:
keep-alive
Cookie:
.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.M_CbfYYiv98=CfDJ8O02-DY9oulCm8oGoZzMmOUzp1dhOWUFeVzQm1OdcKk3o08w1eAIyu4xvJJht1VstSjyBp0PCRX7AHGDpkfj18F2uhHfpvmAS74Lu59TR8YeSdk1srz5SsCT91q9A_OVlzw_pq7vLEE4UgsuNeVtths; amp_6e403e=A_s18mfi3a_Ud1uBEbecRY...1he7uloj6.1he7vppi7.0.0.0; .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider=CfDJ8O02-DY9oulCm8oGoZzMmOWaozRLZVo7aG4iTNHNfGEDMR8Dxzk97L6JeY1f7qjBG2J34AXTx0h-AFH4DcCjO5YF-jki5Ynqr--YYvqrzBvJq1JkFhgiPJH-sASy6Ee9xGAQK5PYNRzZIJgd5-dBQXJhSnwkrQudaeLctzEuZ5R0T-UOv02hXWwXiQXtZRMOPNKgepCYdAwhva_1NtoSrrg7bcURNBWV_qP8SZPwT4UVh18j-__v1bke_5il7uM1T0W-XqQvUUdi3sdSA-ij1pan8hWpvur_vpeMaWI912s_M4_6ImDI0sdIhAM60iVXYjqOArdsdZFOkRlz9fVvlHSYGVEtbZBze6OrTuuSw74oGrxgoaoxpu7PWPUXDpakLzo7avRk3HIwjE55eHi-s9JgeC8v9tqcry5F4lUkpH9OEpxm5-Jz6-pjmPUaYiYRM4HGIiwwGtkAvf7xA-RQKRDwEhuAAM9R8-v2gidT0wP9aReqsXWUcXtyOY2R6JGyf9G-WBR6rc-TCdVMJLPNbOoglIXlLnvVg_9Ylt2ypl5p7r8GS1EfCj0OhhU5LD_iEqBPkGM61ni6Pa1IrAvL1r449yoPBA14_WwPOkx8plXGDYDujKQ0eFDURlBNwHOf3gK2hPSQSIjBxFNqQ2Aa7Sl__BkOvoGpcKAlhMIxRbtGCSNlpNhBPWbDEp32nqccmbtV4RoqJz9O-M2kOjB2m1rDa6aqf-2IMyOTLVLDAQJL_nlkh8h7wvcaFuGXZa7BqYvrJB6ARhq-B4-2d_S4XXGUxen17WmIoMi_6aTf2p43wvMpOsGpko1S0npTXcpB9_vA7VvfqM5TroSF12STIKpAwQSmwKaONQuFdCleeZ4qWTbcAr2uPCvwFJFgEu0kXdo2ZN-H4JBjd3hW52rP3W9Qi0t_fEXRw2Yl_3d3-Ccgdg6kwQUvtTASYJwoHdmRr_EO6SE8jXkKilzuCnhIerzHuo2TzJc8yBXmAcMUXAkJswR6-oSmWn9Nn3fDjfPdypngZiQajY6WKhoHqqscR_xCR-h6GxA-5ypSderV54jC
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
document
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site:
none
Sec-Fetch-User:
?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
1

Does anyone have any solutions or ideas on how I can fix this or at least get the logging enabled to view the issue in more detail?